# How to store only unique images in storage?

Tags: algorithm, image-recognition

I have such problem: I need to store somewhere (on file-system or database - it has no matter) a number of images. And I can with special tool to add new images to storage, but the main problem is in that the tool should to add at storage only truly unique images.
If use approach like hash sum from all pixels of image, then it works until resize of image or change of image (if at least one color is changed by 1 ) then hash-sum will be different but actually images are the same. 
If I use some sort image comparison algorithms that returns "similarity" percent, then problem is in that I should to compare image with a lot number of other images and that process can take a time.
Does anybody can suggest other solution?

Comment: This might be a better fit over at CrossValidated https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [perceptual hash](http://www.phash.org/).

A perceptual hash is a fingerprint of a multimedia file derived from various features from its content. Unlike cryptographic hash functions which rely on the avalanche effect of small changes in input leading to drastic changes in the output, perceptual hashes are "close" to one another if the features are similar.

Answer (score 1):

Before creating the HASH, resize the image to a fixed size  and set it to B/W then create the HASH.